# How can I stop indentfirst from indenting?

Tags: indentation

I'm using `indentfirst` to indent the first lines of my paragraphs. But then I have a bibliography at the end where I want each paragraph to have hanging indents. Something like:

```
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{hanging}
\begin{document}
Some paragraphs here with regular indentation. 
But then suddenly: 
\magicCommandToStopIndentationGoesHere
\magicCommandToStartHangingIndentationGoesHere
And here is my bibliography, with hanging indentation
\end{document}
```

How can I do this? I can't modify any of the latex in my bibliography, or wrap it, really, because it's generated with pandoc-citeproc, so I'm hoping there are magic commands like this.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\date{}

\begin{document}

%%% This should all have first-line indentation 

Hello,

Here is a citation: (Smith 2015, 25).

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

\section*{Works Cited}\label{works-cited}

%%% I can't change anything from here on, since it's automatically generated

%%% This needs to have hanging indentation

Smith, John. 2015. \emph{A Book}. But Imagine if this Publisher had a
really really long name or something that was overflowing; it needed to
be indented hanging-wise Book Press.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually, the bibliography environment/macro you use takes care of this. Is your bibliography not using anything like that? Please complete your MWE so we've got something to play with. This will include a minimal (e.g. one entry) copy of your bibliography, your document class etc.

Comment: please provide a document that shows the problem, indentfirst does not force indentation it just suppresses the  mechanism section headings use to stop indentation bibliographies are normally a list so would not be affected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\everypar` to set up the layout of your bibliography:

Define a new macro with your paragraph settings:

```
\newcommand{\hangworkscited}{%
  \parindent 0em\parskip 1ex
  \everypar={\hangindent 1.3em}}
```

Then call it just after your **Works Cited** section header.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\date{}

\newcommand{\hangworkscited}{%
  \parindent 0em\parskip 1ex
  \everypar={\hangindent 1.3em}}

\begin{document}

%%% This should all have first-line indentation 

Hello,

Here is a citation: (Smith 2015, 25).

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

\section*{Works Cited}\label{works-cited}

\hangworkscited

%%% I can't change anything from here on, since it's automatically generated

%%% This needs to have hanging indentation

Smith, John. 2015. \emph{A Book}. But Imagine if this Publisher had a
really really long name or something that was overflowing; it needed to
be indented hanging-wise Book Press.

Smith, John. 2015. \emph{A Book}. But Imagine if this Publisher had a
really really long name or something that was overflowing; it needed to
be indented hanging-wise Book Press.

Smith, John. 2015. \emph{A Book}. But Imagine if this Publisher had a
really really long name or something that was overflowing; it needed to
be indented hanging-wise Book Press.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]